# Internal 500 Error on Using Angular Subject

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am learning to use Subject from rxjs to send a string to the back end. I console the string from the front end and it prints the expected string. When I look in net core2.1 it is sent as null and not as the string.

This is the error in googlechrome dev window "2:65418/api/stock:1 POST http://localhost:65418/api/stock 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Here is the component code in stock.component.ts file:

```
    post(stock){
     this.api.postStock(stock);
     console.log("this is the stock I posted", stock);
}
```

This is the api service ts code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Subject} from 'rxjs'

import { Cagr } from '../_models/cagr'
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'

const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {

  apiURL = environment.apiUrl;
  stockUrl = this.apiURL + '/api/stock';

  private icarg = new Subject<Cagr[]>();
  Icagr$ = this.icarg.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postStock (stocks) {
    this.http.post(this.stockUrl, stocks, {headers: 
headers}).subscribe(res => {

  console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", res);
},
response => {
  console.log("POST call in error", response);

  })
  }
```

This is the component html code:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <form class="example-form">
        <mat-form-field >
          <input [(ngModel)]="stock" name = "stock" matInput placeholder="Input stock symbol" >
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button (click)="post(stock)" mat-raised-button color="primary">Go</button>
        <div>
```

This is the backend area where I expect to see the string, but is null:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Models.Stock stock)
    {
        _context.Stocks.Add(stock);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok(stock);
    }
```

Comment: One really easy way for you to debug this is to open up the network tab in Chrome and check how the request looks like. Is the body sent as expected, then its a mapping problem with the model.

One thing i don't understand with this code is the use of the Subject part, your subject is only newed up and then turned into a observable. There is no use of it in this code, but i guess you plan to next something in the future.

Comment: @StefanKarlsson looking at the network tab in Chome the payload is the stock I am sending. I use ngmodel in the html file to get the stock string. It  must be on the back end. Thanks. I will add the html code for stock

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you tested your api with any tool like postman/fiddler/swagger. Because from what i know, the internal server error is coming from your api.